# How long can I keep HDPE plastic in an oven for before it starts to burn?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, plastics

I am recycling HDPE plastic (chips) in an oven. I left it in the oven for 10 mins and it melted the outside layer of the plastic fine. When I cut into the plastic with a saw after it cooled, there was a layer that hadn't melted.

I think 180 degrees Celcius is about the right temperature (it's round about the minimum melt temperature for HDPE), but I would like how long I can keep it in the oven for before it combusts?

My thinking is if I leave it in the oven longer than 10 mins, it will also melt the inside. But I especially don't want to leave it in the oven long enough to make nasty combustion fumes.

Any help with time I should leave it in the oven would be appreciated ('practical' answers preferred).

[image: Chips]
[image: Bricks]

Comment: Your spouse or significant other is very accommodating, that's all I can say...

Comment: I hope you're not using the same oven you use for regular cooking.  The vapors from the plastic could deposit themselves on the interior of the oven, and then deposit themselves on your food the next time you cook.  Also, this is best done in a garage with the door open (you want lots of ventilation).

Comment: Practical answer is: "Never do anything like that at home".

Comment: Clean, colourless HDPE is not going to emit toxic fumes, but *recycled* material ?! Anyway, in what way is this "recycling"? You obtain a solid blob of plastic, probably with a lot of air bubbles in it.

Comment: Was going to cut shapes out of it using a bandsaw. When I cut into it previously, there weren't any bubbles, just an unmelted section. Also the plastic in the photo has been folded ... Might get a better sheet if it's cooked for longer.

Comment: The plastic chips were shredded milk jugs.

Comment: Good news: it is not going to combust at 180 °C. Bad news: some toxic fumes will probably be released anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recomend going to a trift store and picking up a cheap panini press, or a toaster oven. On the panini press, theres usually no ability to change temperatures, but I find its extremely hard to melt it unless you walk away for like 20 minutes. On the toaster oven, 160° should be perfect and i've never had it burn at that temperature. I hope this helps :)